# Bootstrap Timeline - Panel across the line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap time from http://www.bootply.com/iqnKkVevFQ. Just got one of the questions answered that really helped...Now I am dealing with another problem.

I want a panel that starts from left side moves across the line and ends at right side. Currently we have either a right panel or a left panel but not one big fat panel :)

[image: panel that starts from left side moves across the line and ends at right side.]

```
.timeline {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 20px 0 20px;
    position: relative;
}

    .timeline:before {
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;
        content: " ";
        width: 3px;
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -1.5px;
    }

    .timeline > li {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }

        .timeline > li:before,
        .timeline > li:after {
            content: " ";
            display: table;
        }

        .timeline > li:after {
            clear: both;
        }

        .timeline > li:before,
        .timeline > li:after {
            content: " ";
            display: table;
        }

        .timeline > li:after {
            clear: both;
        }

        .timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
            width: 46%;
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
            border-radius: 2px;
            padding: 20px;
            position: relative;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
        }

            .timeline > li > .timeline-panel:before {
                position: absolute;
                top: 26px;
                right: -15px;
                display: inline-block;
                border-top: 15px solid transparent;
                border-left: 15px solid #ccc;
                border-right: 0 solid #ccc;
                border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
                content: " ";
            }

            .timeline > li > .timeline-panel:after {
                position: absolute;
                top: 27px;
                right: -14px;
                display: inline-block;
                border-top: 14px solid transparent;
                border-left: 14px solid #fff;
                border-right: 0 solid #fff;
                border-bottom: 14px solid transparent;
                content: " ";
            }

        .timeline > li > .timeline-badge {
            color: #fff;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            line-height: 50px;
            font-size: 1.4em;
            text-align: center;
            position: absolute;
            top: 16px;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -25px;
            background-color: #999999;
            z-index: 100;
            border-top-right-radius: 50%;
            border-top-left-radius: 50%;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
        }

        .timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel {
            float: right;
        }

            .timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel:before {
                border-left-width: 0;
                border-right-width: 15px;
                left: -15px;
                right: auto;
            }

            .timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel:after {
                border-left-width: 0;
                border-right-width: 14px;
                left: -14px;
                right: auto;
            }

        .timeline > li > .timeline-panel.myinverted{
            float: right;
        }

            .timeline > li > .timeline-panel.myinverted:before {
                border-left-width: 0;
                border-right-width: 15px;
                left: -15px;
                right: auto;
            }

            .timeline > li > .timeline-panel.myinverted:after {
                border-left-width: 0;
                border-right-width: 14px;
                left: -14px;
                right: auto;
            }


.timeline-badge.primary {
    background-color: #2e6da4 !important;
}

.timeline-badge.success {
    background-color: #3f903f !important;
}

.timeline-badge.warning {
    background-color: #f0ad4e !important;
}

.timeline-badge.danger {
    background-color: #d9534f !important;
}

.timeline-badge.info {
    background-color: #5bc0de !important;
}

.timeline-title {
    margin-top: 0;
    color: inherit;
}

.timeline-body > p,
.timeline-body > ul {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

    .timeline-body > p + p {
        margin-top: 5px;
    }

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    ul.timeline:before {
        left: 40px;
    }

    ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
        width: calc(100% - 90px);
        width: -moz-calc(100% - 90px);
        width: -webkit-calc(100% - 90px);
    }

    ul.timeline > li > .timeline-badge {
        left: 15px;
        margin-left: 0;
        top: 16px;
    }

    ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
        float: right;
    }

        ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel:before {
            border-left-width: 0;
            border-right-width: 15px;
            left: -15px;
            right: auto;
        }

        ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel:after {
            border-left-width: 0;
            border-right-width: 14px;
            left: -14px;
            right: auto;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heres some additional CSS to add to your sheet that will allow for a new called on the `li` called `timeline-fullwidth`

**HTML**

```
    <li class="timeline-fullwidth">
      <div class="timeline-badge default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></div>
      <div class="timeline-panel">
        ...
      </div>
    </li>
```

**CSS**

```
    .timeline > li.timeline-fullwidth > .timeline-panel {
        width:100%;
        margin-top:90px;
    }

        .timeline > li.timeline-fullwidth > .timeline-panel:before {
            border-top: 0 solid #ccc;
            border-left: 14px solid transparent;
            border-right: 14px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 14px solid #ccc;
            left: 50%;
            right: auto;
            top: -15px;
            margin-left: -14px;
        }

        .timeline > li.timeline-fullwidth > .timeline-panel:after {
            border-top: 0 solid #fff;
            border-left: 14px solid transparent;
            border-right: 14px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 14px solid #fff;
            left: 50%;
            right: auto;
            top: -14px;
            margin-left: -14px;
        }
```

had to update some of the other css styles to handle the new style:

```
.timeline > li {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1; /* added this to put the list items on top of the central line */
}
.timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
        background:#FFF; /* add this so that our panels arent transparent allowing you to see the central line*/
        width: 46%;
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
        border-radius: 2px;
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
        box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
    }
```

**[new bootply](http://www.bootply.com/pnmkpe4Wwb)**